# how to make UI on ubuntu back to "normal" after using Wine?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, wine

I tried running a program on wine (a windows program) on my ubuntu 10.04 box...but now, the browser and everything has the look and feel of a Windows 3.x box...I don't know what happened or how to reset it...help?

Answer (score 0):

Wine does support some basic theming of window styles - See [Configuring Wine](http://www.winehq.org/docs/wineusr-guide/config-wine-main).

Detailed explanation of what you need to do is...

1. Search for the folder .wine (usually found at /home/(user name)/.wine;
2. add a folder called "Themes",
   3 visit http://search.deviantart.com/?sectio...3A5&q=msstyles
3. download a theme,
4. add the .msstyles file (into a folder of its own) under the (newly created) "Themes" folder,
5. type winecfg in a terminal - Or find it under WINE Menuitem.
6. Under Desk Top Integration, select "Install Theme" then select the .msstyles file.

The actual file your looking for to add a theme is .msstyles.

A article which includes a python script that automates theming [from Webup8](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/06/make-wine-applications-look-like-your.html).